# "Ball" cover for one group in 3d plot

Tags: r, 3d, nearest-neighbor, rgl

I have data containing 3 dimensions.

I calculated nearest neighbors within a radius of specific data point (using `nn2`)

Then, I plotted 3d plot of my data (using `plot3d` from `rgl` library):

```
plot3d(dfrm[1:3], col=rainbow(2)[dfrm$col], size...)
```

So, I have 3 colored plot:

- 1st color- my data point
- 2nd color- point within the radius
- 3rd color- rest of the points

Is there a way to cover my 1st and 2nd color groups with a transparent "ball"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `spheres3d()` function to draw a sphere.  You need to specify the center (presumably your data point) and radius.  Use something like `col = "black", alpha = 0.2` to make it transparent, and `aspect = "iso"` in the `plot3d()` call so it's not rescaled.  For example,

```
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(30), ncol=3)
dist <- apply(xyz, 1, function(pt) sqrt(sum((pt - xyz[1,])^2)))
radius <- 1
plot3d(xyz, col=c("black", ifelse(dist[-1] < radius, "green", "red")),
       aspect = "iso", size = 3)
spheres3d(xyz[1,,drop=FALSE], col="black", alpha = 0.2, radius=radius)
```

which gives

[image]

The green points are inside the sphere, the red ones are outside it.